# Is it possible to change the HTTP headers for the retry request generated from NSURLSessionDelegate:didReceiveChallenge()?

Tags: ios

My app makes a request to a server with headers:

```
x-header-a : "something"
x-header-b : "something else"
x-header-c : "more something"
```

Then when the server responds with HTTP 401/WWW-Authenticate and `didReceiveChallenge:` gets invoked I pass a `NSURLCredential` to the completion handler.

However for the resulting retry request that gets sent I want the outgoing header content to be:

```
x-header-a : "something"
x-header-b : "something else"
authorization : "some stuff"
```

In particular I do not want x-header-c to be included again.
Can the outgoing headers be altered within `didReceiveChallenge:`?

There's requests within the NSURLSessionTask parameter but they are read only.